# Android Intent extras not Updating

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am making a tic-tac-toe game.

Whenever there is a result, i do an intent to another activity and also pass some data --- about the winner.

Then i get the data in other activity through getIntent(). However that data doesnt seem to update after once i click the reset button which gets back to play screen

Here is my playing activity

```
if (themeChosen == 0) {
                if (gameState[position[0]] == 0) {
                    //Noughts Won!
                    Log.i("winner", "normal1");
                    resultTextView.setText("Winner: Nought");

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), LocalGameResultActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("winner", "normal1");
                    startActivity(intent);

                    resetGame(); //Reset Game after Result
                } else {
                    //Cross Won!

                    Log.i("winner", "normal2");
                    resultTextView.setText("Winner: Cross");

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), LocalGameResultActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("winner", "normal2");
                    startActivity(intent);

                    resetGame(); //Reset Game after Result
                }
            }
```

And here is my recieving activity code

```
 String winnerString = getIntent().getStringExtra("winner"); //Getting Winner

        //Handling Winner Situations
        //Normal
        if(winnerString.equals("normal1")){
            dummyTextView.setText("Noughts Won!");
        } else if(winnerString.equals("normal2")){
            dummyTextView.setText("Crosses Won!");
        }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Remember that in Java all executable code must be in a method in a class. I am sure you know this already. Leaving out these details omits information that helps us understand your question better.

Comment: Is the recieving activity code placed in `onActivityResult()` method? I see that you start your activity with `startActivity()` and you should with `startActivityForResult()`. After that you should call `onActivityResult()` and take the new values